# Why isn't an implicit conversion from int to intBox working in Json.decode or default modelbinding?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding, implicit-conversion

EDIT: removed first part of the question, as it was misleading and not completely pertinent.

For various reasons, I've come to the point where I could really use the ability to box some of my Post body parameters in their model.

I started this just accepting the default model binder would just work™, which it does, but not for ints(?!). Example:

```
public class IntBox
{
    public int Value;

    public IntBox(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator IntBox(int value)
    {
        return new IntBox(value);
    }
}

public class StringBox
{
    public string Value;

    public StringBox(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator StringBox(string value)
    {
        return new StringBox(value);
    }
}

public class BoolBox
{
    public bool Value;

    public BoolBox(bool value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator BoolBox(bool value)
    {
        return new BoolBox(value);
    }
}

public class NeedQuery : StateFullQuery
{
    public StringBox[] TestStrings { get; set; } //"TestStrings":["a","b"]
    public IntBox[] TestInts { get; set; } //"TestInts":[1,2,3,4]
    public BoolBox[] TestBools { get; set; } //"TestBools":[true,false]
}

//Inside Controller:
public string Post([FromBody]NeedQuery query)
{
    //At this point query.TestStrings contains two StringBoxes with the expected values. As does query.TestBools
    // However, query.TestInts is empty.
}
```

What am I missing?! What's so special about Ints that they can't be implicitly cast by the Modelbinder? How do I get around this?

Would really appreciate help with this one; without a large rewrite I'm blocked until I can figure it out.

NOTE: When I say I need to box the int values, that's a simplification of the problem for the sake of the post, it's a bit more complicated than simply boxing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

This doesn't work:

```
public class IntBox
{
    public int Value;

    public IntBox(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator IntBox(int value)
    {
        return new IntBox(value);
    }
}
```

This does work:

```
public class IntBox
{
    public int Value;

    public IntBox(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator IntBox(Int64 value)
    {
        return new IntBox(value);
    }
}
```

So obviously there's some silliness with 64/32 bit conversion there. I will probably have to implement my implicit conversion for both 32 and 64 bit ints, but at least I can stop pulling my hair out. And maybe this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is (in short) that implicit casts are inferred at compile time, while the model binder uses reflection at runtime to set the value, at which point there are two different - incompatible - types.

The simplest solution to deal with situations like this is usually to have (for example) an `int[]` property on your model, bind to that and have it simply map to an `IntBox[]` property manually (e.g. via custom accessors).

I won't post a "full" solution since - as you've said - your example is simplified; however, hopefully this is enough information for you to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: If this was the case, why does the implicit cast to string and bool work in the second example, but not the Int?

Comment: @Glitcher that is a good question - I'm surprised that works (https://dotnetfiddle.net/cztCKK). If that's the behaviour you're seeing then there must be something else happening for these properties before the default model binder reaches the usual path for setting properties...

Comment: I'm working around it at the moment thanks to your answer, but I would really like to know why this fails so badly

Comment: The reason it fails is because it uses `PropertyDescriptor.SetValue` to set the property at runtime - I'm more interested in why it apparently *works* in the other cases

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that [FromBody] uses PropertyDescriptor.SetValue? Because If going down the Json.Decode route, all implict conversions fail. It's only when using [FromBody] that only int fails (which it does silently)